# What is the default COST of a CTest test

Tags: cmake, ctest

One of the properties you can set for a [ctest](/questions/tagged/ctest) test is its [`COST`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_test/COST.html). Tests are run in descending `COST` order.

But if you set a `COST` for only *some* of your tests, how are those tests ordered with respect to the tests that do not have an explicit `COST`? That is, what is the default `COST` of a test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimentation with CMake 3.7 suggests that the default test `COST` is 0. As it runs tests in descending `COST` order, it will run your tests with explicit positive `COST` properties before the tests without `COST` properties.

Comment: The absence of details like this is why I curse the CMake documentation.